# JQuery reversing SlideToggle in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have the following simple code:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
    $('.menu ul li:has("ul")').hover(function() {
        $('>ul', this).stop().slideToggle();
    });
});
```

I'm using the 'no conflict' way of firing jQuery but for some reason my slide toggle is closing on hover rather than opening! What am I doing wrong? I'm sure its simple but I just can't see it.

An example can be seen here http://ng1club.everythingcreative.co.uk

Comment: As an aside, you shouldn't be using `$('> ul', this)`, the direct descendant selector used with context is no longer reccomended.

Comment: Your menu is completely messed up, padding, height and other things seems to animate in all sorts of ways? There must be something else going on, does the theme or some plugin also animate the menu.

Comment: This appears to be working fine in this small [fiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/VYkVL/). I suggest you take a look at the surrounding elements to your menu. Particularly with regard to `display`, or perhaps as @adeneo stated other animations that may be occurring.

Comment: @Goose - The menu does seem to start out with `display:none` (inspected in Chrome), so it should in theory work, but as I've previously noted, something is interfering and the animations are going all "wonky", so there must be more code somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` instead. Sometimes `hover` without the second function as a hover out, triggers twice.

```
    $('.menu ul li:has("ul")').mouseenter(function() {
        $('>ul', this).stop().slideDown();
    }).mouseleave(function() {
        $('>ul', this).stop().slideUp();
    });
```

Comment: Both these answers seems to be **exactly** the same as the OP's code ?

Comment: Unless I'm doing something wrong neither of these answers actually do anything

Comment: @JosephGregory Can create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? and show the exact html structure of the page?

Answer (score 0):

Try this according to documentation you can use hover and apply effect on hover and hover out

```
jQuery('.menu ul li:has("ul")').hover(
  function() {
      jQuery('>ul', this).stop().slideDown();
  }, function() {
      jQuery('>ul', this).stop().slideUp();
  }
);
```

[**.hover()**](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

[**Sample Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/k8xRW/)